React-Native issue with Token Refresh Management with Axios Client
I've made an interceptor for 401 codes, the interceptor works as expected:

A first request returns a 401
The client asks the backend for new tokens
All the subsequent requests that return a 401 get saved in a queue
The tokens are locally updated
The new tokens are (supposedly) used for every request saved
If something fails (e.g. refresh_token is expired too) a logout is forced

Guess what? It's not working.
It appears as if the requests headers are correctly updated, the resulting data is received from the components calling the API but still a logout is triggered.
Code:
static {
    BackendClient.instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: Globals.ServerName
    });

    // Interceptor to handle 401 errors
    BackendClient.instance.interceptors.response.use(
        (response: any) => {
            return response;
        },
        async (error: any) => {
            const originalRequest = error.config;
            console.log("[!] - ORIGINAL REQ: ", originalRequest);
            const url = error.request.responseURL;

            if (error.response && error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
                console.log("[!] - INTERCEPTED ERROR 401 FOR API:", url);

                if (isRefreshing) {
                    // If the token is already being refreshed, add the original request to the queue
                    console.log("\t\t[!] - Adding request to refresh queue...", refreshQueue?.length + 1);
                    return new Promise((resolve) => {
                        refreshQueue.push({
                            request: originalRequest,
                            resolve: resolve // Resolve the Promise when the queued request is resolved
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    isRefreshing = true;
                    originalRequest._retry = true;
                    try {
                        console.log("\t[!] - Refreshing token...");
                        // Retrieve the refresh token from LocalStorage
                        const refreshToken = await LocalStorage.getItem(Globals.STORAGE_KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN);
                        if (debug) {
                            const oldToken = await LocalStorage.getItem(Globals.STORAGE_KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
                            console.log("\t[!] - Old token is:", oldToken);
                        }
                        // Execute the function to get a new access token
                        const newToken = await BackendClient.getNewAccessToken(refreshToken);
                        // Update the access token in the original request
                        originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${newToken}`;
                        console.log("\t[!] - TOKEN REFRESHED: Resolving previous requests, token:", newToken);
                        // Retry the original request with the new access token
                        const response = await BackendClient.instance(originalRequest);
                        await Promise.all(
                            refreshQueue.map(async (queuedRequest: any) => {
                                console.log("\t[!] - Resolving queued request for:", queuedRequest.request.url);
                                console.log("\t[!] - Old request headers:", queuedRequest.request.headers);
                                // Update the headers of the queued request before resolving it
                                queuedRequest.request.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${newToken}`;
                                console.log("\t[!] - New request headers:", queuedRequest.request.headers);
                                // Resolve the queued request
                                queuedRequest.resolve(await BackendClient.instance(queuedRequest.request));
                            })
                        );
                        refreshQueue = [];
                        return response;
                    } catch (error) {
                        // We log out; 
                        if (error?.response?.status == 401 || error?.response?.status == 429) {
                            console.log("\t[!] LOGOUT due to", error);
                            await LocalStorage.removeItem(Globals.STORAGE_KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
                            await LocalStorage.removeItem(Globals.STORAGE_KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN);
                            BackendClient.resetCallback();
                            BackendClient.dispatch(removeAllUpcomingEvents());
                            BackendClient.dispatch(removeAllSavedEvents());
                            BackendClient.setShowToast({ show: true, textKey: textKeys.TOAST_LoginAgain });
                        } else {
                            console.log("\t[!] ERROR ", error, error?.response, error.response?.status);
                        }

                        // throw refreshError;
                    } finally {
                        console.log("[!] End.");
                        isRefreshing = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            // If it's not a 401 error, reject the error
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    );
}

Logs where:

[...] means the I trimmed the log
"BACKEND  - apiName" means apiName has just been invoked
[!] means the log is relative to the token refresh mechanism

 LOG  BACKEND - getUserInfo
 LOG  BACKEND - getUserEvents
 LOG  [!] - ORIGINAL REQ:  {"adapter": ["xhr", "http", "fetch"], "baseURL": "https://backend.com", "data": undefined, "env": {"Blob": [Function Blob], "FormData": [Function FormData]}, "headers": {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Authorization": "Bearer eyJh[...]BoMk"}, "maxBodyLength": -1, "maxContentLength": -1, "method": "get", "timeout": 0, "transformRequest": [[Function transformRequest]], "transformResponse": [[Function transformResponse]], "transitional": {"clarifyTimeoutError": false, "forcedJSONParsing": true, "silentJSONParsing": true}, "url": "/events/my-events?page=1", "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus], "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"}
 LOG  [!] - INTERCEPTED ERROR 401 FOR API: https://backend.com/events/my-events/?page=1
 LOG    [!] - Refreshing token...
 LOG    [!] - Old token is: eyJh[...]BoMk
 LOG       [!] - BACKEND - getNewAccessToken
 LOG    [!] - Correctly got new tokens.
 LOG  [!] - ORIGINAL REQ:  {"adapter": ["xhr", "http", "fetch"], "baseURL": "https://backend.com", "data": undefined, "env": {"Blob": [Function Blob], "FormData": [Function FormData]}, "headers": {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Authorization": "Bearer eyJ[...]BoMk"}, "maxBodyLength": -1, "maxContentLength": -1, "method": "get", "timeout": 0, "transformRequest": [[Function transformRequest]], "transformResponse": [[Function transformResponse]], "transitional": {"clarifyTimeoutError": false, "forcedJSONParsing": true, "silentJSONParsing": true}, "url": "/user/me", "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus], "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"}
 LOG  [!] - INTERCEPTED ERROR 401 FOR API: https://backend.com/user/me
 LOG       [!] - Adding request to refresh queue... 1
 LOG  LocalStorage [SET] - successfully stored access_token
 LOG  LocalStorage [SET] - successfully stored refresh_token
 LOG    [!] - TOKEN REFRESHED: Resolving previous requests, token: eyJh[...]ewB4
 LOG  BACKEND - getUserInfo
 LOG  BACKEND - getUserEvents
 LOG  user data received [... CORRECT DATA FROM getUserInfo IN COMPONENT...]
 LOG  BACKEND - getFilteredEvents
 LOG  [!] - ORIGINAL REQ:  {"_retry": true, "adapter": ["xhr", "http", "fetch"], "baseURL": "https://backend.com", "data": undefined, "env": {"Blob": [Function Blob], "FormData": [Function FormData]}, "headers": {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Authorization": "Bearer eyJh[...]ewB4"}, "maxBodyLength": -1, "maxContentLength": -1, "method": "get", "timeout": 0, "transformRequest": [[Function transformRequest]], "transformResponse": [[Function transformResponse]], "transitional": {"clarifyTimeoutError": false, "forcedJSONParsing": true, "silentJSONParsing": true}, "url": "/events/my-events?page=1", "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus], "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"}
 LOG    [!] LOGOUT due to [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401]
 LOG  LocalStorage [DEL] - access_token successfully removed.
 LOG  LocalStorage [DEL] - refresh_token successfully removed.
 LOG  [!] End.


I'm confused and can't understand what's happening here.
It seems like the last request broke everything but it's been made with the correct token, so what?
